# How to obtain table iterator with ColdFusion's Reactor?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, reactor

I'm using Reactor with ColdFusion for ORM, and I know how to get a Gateway object for a table X which provides a `getAll` method which returns a query with all records in a table X, but instead I want a object iterator so that I can use `getRelatedIterator`s on each record for data in related tables Y, Z, etc..

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a CFDUMP on the record - you should see an iterator function such as get[link_name]Iterator().

If you don't see it - you probably haven't set up the relationship correctly on the reactor.xml.

For instance if you have this on your reactor.xml

```
   <object name="Author">
    <hasMany name="Book">
        <link name="Author_Book" />
    </hasMany>
   </object>
```

You then can use the object iterator like the following:

```
<cfset objAuthorBookIterator = objAuthor.getAuthor_BookIterator()>
```